# traversal while printing linked lists

Tags: c++, pointers, linked-list

I have a function that prints linked lists. The code works fine. but I have problem understanding the function. Here is the function

```
void print(node* x)
{
    while(x != NULL)
    {
        cout << x -> info << " ";
        x = x -> next;
    }
}
```

where the `node` structure is

```
struct node
{
    int info;
    node *next;
};
```

The statement `x = x -> next` puzzles me. Won't it change the value of `x` to that of it's `next` node? I don't see a plausible solution to my question. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: *Won't it change the value of x to that of it's next node?*  -- Yes.  Now what don't you understand about that?  How are you going to get to the next link in the chain?

Comment: I didn't know the function makes a copy of the original array. (Was just in grade 12)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`node *x` defines x as a pointer, actually it is just a value stores some memory address.

It would not change the the original list unless `x->next->field = VALUE` is performed.

Comment: Yes, but don't you do something similar while inserting new nodes?

Comment: it is `x = x -> next` not `x->next = x `

Comment: so `x->next = y` makes `x` point to `y` and does not alter any value?

Comment: @FaraazAhmad No, `x->next = y` makes `x->next` point to the same thing that `y` points to - that is, `x->next` has the same value as `y`. `x` isn't modified, but `*x` is.

Comment: Thanks for all the help and patience.